# ng-repeat track by $index breaks image field sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat table with a handful of columns. One of te columns is an image field. Here is a snippet with the image column and one of the others:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="insight in insights | orderBy:sort track by $index">
            <td>
                <select ng-model="insight.type" ng-change="setType(insight)" required="required">
                    <option value="INSIGHT">Insight</option>
                    <option value="EVIDENCE">Evidence</option>
                </select>
            </td>
<!--Image thing-->
            <td>
                <a ng-href="{{:: insight.imgurl}}" target="_blank"><img class="full" wb-lazy-load-image="{{:: insight.imgurl}}" data-height="600" data-width="800"></a>
            </td>
        ...
    </tbody>
```

As it stands, when I click to sort by a column, all of the columns sort with their associated row, *except* for the image row; it stays in the same spot.

If I remove the `track by $index` code at the `<tr>` it reorders all the columns as expected.

Any idea why or what I can do to fix that?

**Edit:**
FWIW - `sort` is defined in my Controller as: `$scope.sort = ['-primary', '-live'];`

**Edit (Solution):**
I ended up removing the one time binding as suggested in the accepted answer and it fixed the issue. However, after some consideration, we decided we'd rather have the performance gain of our one time, lazy loads than the `track by` performance as the lists would be small.

For anyone else who has this issue, one time binding with the images in conjuction with track by $index seemed to be the issue in this case.

Comment: try making sort a property of insight object as insight.sort

Comment: check out my code snippts below.  I modified what was posted on angularjs doc for orderby: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: if I had to make a random guess here, does it work if you don't use one time bindings? i.e. remove the `::` from the binding expression.  I suspect it may have something to do with the way that one time bindings interact with that `wb-lazy-load-image` directive, but it's not something I can reproduce right this second.

Comment: @Claies - That worked! code is the following: `<tr ng-repeat="insight in insights | orderBy:sort track by $index"> .... <a ng-href="{{ insight.imgurl}}" target="_blank"><img class="full" wb-lazy-load-image="{{ insight.imgurl}}" data-height="600" data-width="800"></a>` . If you want to submit an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the one time binding syntax is the culprit.  using `{{::insight.imgurl}}` would create a one time binding, where the watcher is removed from this element.  However, when used in combination with `wb-lazy-load-image`, it would appear that the directive believes it is getting a two way binding but is in fact getting a one way binding.

My best guess without seeing how this directive works is that the directive takes the `insight.imgurl` and performs a network call to find the image.  Then the filter causes the array to change order, but the directive isn't aware that the order has changed, due to the one way binding.  Therefore, the directive loads the image in the incorrect place.  Removing `track by $index` would cause the `ng-repeat` to be handled differently in the `$digest` loop, causing the problem directive to be completely re-rendered.

Removing `::` from the binding to the directive input should allow the directive to function as intended, even without a full re-render. In general, `::` is only intended for use in cases where the expressions will be permanent after rendering; in this case, they are not permanent due to the order filter.

Comment: This did work. However what I ended up doing for production was removing the `track by` bit. We wanted the one time binding performance more than we wanted the `track by` performance gain at the moment. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="orderByExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('orderByExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.friends =
          [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10,sort:['-age','-name']},
           {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19,sort:['-age','-name']},
           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21,sort:['-age','-name']},
           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35,sort:['-age','-name']},
           {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29,sort:['-age','-name']}];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:sort track by $index">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```

According to the AngularJS Doc:

- **Note: track by must always be the last expression:**
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

An example which might help you:

```html
<div ng-repeat="model in collection | orderBy: 'id' as filtered_result track by model.id">
    {{model.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Changed to this: `<tr ng-repeat="insight in insights | orderBy:sort as results track by $index">` and have the same behavior :-/. +1 for docs on `track by` at the end tho